# Pass multiple values in one parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
Create procedure [dbo].[sp_Sample]
    @param1 varchar(100)
as
   DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
   SET @param1 = REPLACE(@param1,',',''',''')
   SET @Sql = 'select * from tblSample where col1 IN (''' + @param1 + ''')'
Go

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[sp_Sample]
     @Escalation = N'SIM4'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

When I execute this procedure displays nothing

Suggest me if anything wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing your dynamic query, try this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Sample] @param1 VARCHAR(100)
AS
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @param1 = Replace(@param1, ',', ''',''')
    SET @Sql = 'select * from tblSample where col1 IN ('''
               + @param1 + ''')'
    --PRINT @Sql 
    exec sp_executesql @Sql
GO 

Exec sp_Sample '1001'
GO
```

Note : `PRINT` statement will print the query string, uncomment it and check your query.

Comment: Thanks for respond deepak.

Comment: when i exec [sp_Sample]
'value1' its giving error : The name 'select * from tblSample where col1 IN ('value1')' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: but when when i execute the same query directly it executes well

Comment: I have made some changes check now

Comment: Replace(@param1, ',', ''',''') all these are single quotes only?

Comment: the same script i was copied into sql, but no result

Comment: have you checked your dynamic sql string by printing it? is it correct? because it is working in my SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things which needs to be updated here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Sample] 
@param1 nvarchar(100),-- change 1 as you have added N for  @Escalation
@return int OUTPUT -- change 2: define output variable for value the sp will return
AS  

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

    /* Build the SQL string one time.*/
    SET @SQLString =
         N'SELECT @return_valueOUT = Id from tblSample where col1 
         IN (''' + @param1 + ''')' ;

    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@return_valueOUT int OUTPUT';

    -- dynamically execute the query
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
            @return_valueOUT=@return OUTPUT;

RETURN
GO

-- Declare the variable to receive the output value of the procedure.
DECLARE @return_value int;
-- Execute the procedure specifying a input parameter
-- and saving the output value in the variable @return_value
EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_Sample] N'Test', @return = @return_value OUTPUT;
-- Display the value returned by the procedure.
-- as @return_value is an int cast it to varchar
Select 'Return Value = '  + convert(varchar(10),@return_value); 
GO
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/RHPMR31825)</kbd>