# How to pass multiple value in one parameter in one variable to OLEDB Source of SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to pass multiple values as one parameter. e.g: I need to get the `employeeID` in (1,2,3,4,5), `employeeID` field data type is Integer.

Query:

```
select * from emp where employeeID = ?
```

I Create a variable `'v_employeeID'` with the value 1 and passed the parameter mapping in OLEDB Source. I can pass one value but I cant pass multiple value.

Comment: OleDb does not support table valued parameters. You need the classes in System.Data.SqlClient for that.

Comment: = operator will not work for multiple value in your query..use IN operator to filter out the employee id

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355232/pass-multiple-values-in-one-parameter-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to make your entire query a variable.  If your `@employeeID` variable contains "1,2,3" (it will have to be a string variable, by the way), then your `@SQLQuery` variable would be:

```
"select * from emp where employeeID IN (" + @employeeID +")"
```

Then in your OLEDB Source, use the "Query from Variable" option, and use the `@SQLQuery` variable as the source.

Comment: Hi Tab Alleman, Thanks for your help.

I want to know more about it from you that if I give some input in the "Value" field of the Variable @employeeID e.g(1,2,3) then it works fine but if I keep "Value" field blank then a Incorrect syntax error is coming from oledb source.

Error: "Incorrect syntax near ')'.".

In my cases the ssis package will be execute from a C# application and the user will input the variable value from a desktop application.

Please advise me to solve this issue.

Comment: What would be the desired solution?   What do you want the package to do if the user leaves the  "Value" field blank?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GenerateIDs]
(
 @psCSString VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS @otTemp TABLE(sID VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @sTemp VARCHAR(10)

 WHILE LEN(@psCSString) > 0
 BEGIN
  SET @sTemp = LEFT(@psCSString, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @psCSString) - 1, -1),
                    LEN(@psCSString)))
  SET @psCSString = SUBSTRING(@psCSString,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @psCSString), 0),
                               LEN(@psCSString)) + 1, LEN(@psCSString))
  INSERT INTO @otTemp VALUES (@sTemp)
 END

RETURN
END
```

Which will return you the table of IDs when passed in format : `'1,2,3,4'`

Such as :

```
select *
from fn_GenerateIDs('1,2,3')
```

Results:

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
```

And then you would have to pass parameter in varchar format : "1,2,3,4,5"
and compare it with the Employee table as :

```
    select * from emp where    
    EXISTS ( select 1 from fn_GenerateIDs('1,2,3') where employeeID = sID)
```

Another option if you are using SQL Server 2016 is to use a newly added function STRING_SPLIT

Which require 2 parameters: String of ids, and a separator

Such as:

```
select * from dbo.emp
inner join string_split('1,2,3,4',',') on dbo.emp.employeeID = value
```

Comment: This is probably one of the the worst sting splitting function you can choose.  Read Arron Bertrand's [split string the right way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).