# Multiple values for parameter in SSIS ( OLEDB Source)

Tags: sql, ssis-2012

How to pass multiple values for a parameter in OLEDB source , i tried using IN in SQL Query and mapped the parameter as well ,but it didn't work.

i got this link ,[How to pass multiple value in one parameter in one variable to OLEDB Source of SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213994/how-to-pass-multiple-value-in-one-parameter-in-one-variable-to-oledb-source-of-s) , but am not sure about performance . Any other suggestions ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are trying to build a query, or use a stored procedure or?  Please post here what you already tried.

Comment: using dynamic sql in your variable will not be easy if you have a long query. create a stored procedure or function only to split in your input variables seems kind of over engineered. If you are using SSMS 2016+ (VS 2017 MAYBE), check if build-in  `STRING_SPLIT` using over that string variables can help you